# Move From Reporting Services 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have 2 servers:

- SQL Server 2005 w/ Reporting Services Configured
- SQL Server 2008

I need to move the reporting services stuff from 2005 to 2008 so we can decommission the 2005 machine.

Can someone give me all the necessary steps to get things moved over?

Answer (score 1):

I migrating the data using this:

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

Comment: I used that to jump from '05 to 08R2 also. It worked perfectly. To be fair though, our SSRS setup is fairly simple.